# Using an If Statement in Crontab To Generate an Alert

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron

I have a server in which there are about a 100 Cron jobs that run various PHP scripts. The task at hand is to generate an alert any time an error occurs in the execution of a PHP script.

The Crons are set as follows:

```
30 08 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/phpscirpt1.php > /var/www/html/phpscript1.log 2>&1
```

What I have tried is placing an `&&` in the end but this generates the Alert Email either way

```
30 08 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/phpscript1.php > /var/www/html/phpscript1.log 2>&1 && <Generate Mail>
```

The ideal case that should work would be

```
 /bin/bash /home/myUser/testfile.sh > /home/myUser/testfile.log 2>&1 ; [$? == 1] && /bin/bash script.sh
```

The following is just a sample for testing purposes, when

```
/bin/bash /home/myUser/testfile.sh > /home/myUser/testfile.log 2>&1
```

is executed testfile.sh only creates a directory. When the above command is executed the first time `echo $?` gives the output `0`, but running the command again return `1`, because the scripts returns and logs an error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/myUser/testdir': File exists
```

And Basically this is what is required that is whenever the script in a cron fails it should generate an Alert in the form of an Email. In the above example `script.sh` contains a `mail -s` command to send the Email.

But when the complete command is executed an error is returned which is as follows

```
/bin/bash /home/myUser/testfile.sh > /home/myUser/testfile.log 2>&1 ; [$? == 1] && /bin/bash script.sh
-bash: [1: command not found
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance that could be provided in resolving this error. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically your solution is good. You have just made simple bash syntax error.
You have to put spaces around '[' and ']' characters:

```
[ $? == 1 ]
```

I've tested it on my box and it works. I would also suggest to test error code as not equal 0 (*[ $? -ne 0 ]*), unless you are sure that you want to react only on error code 1.

Comment: BTW "==" may not work everywhere. Better use "=" or "-eq".

Comment: Thank you this worked. Very much appreciated. And thanks for the recommendations as well. I will surely follow through.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the following should work:

```
30 08 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/phpscript1.php > /var/www/html/phpscript1.log 2>&1 || <Generate Mail>
30 08 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/phpscript1.php > /var/www/html/phpscript1.log 2>&1 ; [ $? -ne 0 ] && <Generate Mail>
```

The first uses a logical OR `||` instead of logical AND `&&` which is based off of the return value from your script (0 is success anything else is failure).

The second needed a space between the `[` and the `$?` to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion this worked. Much appreciated.